# Windows Phone 7 Control Caching - 'Element is already the child of another element'

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to speed up my windows phone 7 page load times.  I have a 'static' page that has a dynamically created in a Panorama control - static meaning that the content never changes.

On the first load I look at my config file, create the individual PanoramaItem controls and add them to the main Panorama control.  I'm trying to keep a List in a static place so that the initial creation would only happen once and I could just add a fully rendered version to my Panorama control when the page was rendered.

Works fine on first load, but when I try to add the cached PanoramaItems to the Panorama control I get the message "Element is already the child of another element".  This makes sense since I already added before.  But I can see a way to disconnect the PanoramaItems with the first Panorama control...

I could be going about the control caching thing all wrong as well...  Let me know if there's another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Panorama.Items.Remove(pivotItem) for this

As an example

With the following page fields

```
PanoramaItem pi;
bool blahShown = false;
```

On the press of this button, the control is first instantiated and displayed and on subsequent presses removed and readded without instantiation.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    if (pi == null) {
        pi = new PanoramaItem();
        pi.Header = "blah";
    }

    if (blahShown) {
        Pano.Items.Remove(pi);
        blahShown = false;
    } else {
        Pano.Items.Add(pi);
        blahShown = true;
    }


}
```